# Android ListView hide data

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` that gets text from a site. It reads from a textfile(s) data like this
Name
Address
Number
and the textfile is the name of the id every person has. Now I want to get the id when I press on a listview item, is there anyway to store data on a listview item?
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You must made your own custom adapter and custom view for the listview and a json parser. Is way too broad to explain here and was response many, many times. Post your code so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use the adapter like: `ArrayAdapter<Person>` where `Person` class holds all of your data

Comment: Whic id are you referring??

Comment: Well every person has an id like this "084984386532" and thats the name of the text file that holds the data

Comment: create a class (POJO) that holds all the data you need and use it in your `ArrayAdapter` as i commented above

Comment: If id is the name of the text file,then how are you assuming to get id on list item click? You want to get same id for all list item click?Or is it a field in your file like name,address etc.??

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.Post your code

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: follow above link you get what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a custom adapter instead of using just the ArrayAdapter.

Here is an example of one:
https://github.com/kweaver00/android-learning/blob/master/ListView/CustomAdapter%20-%20Custom%20Rows/CustomAdapter/app/src/main/java/com/weaverprojects/customadapter/CustomAdapter.java

So you want to write in the CustomAdapterClass:

```
CustomObjectThatHasJustStringAndId singleRow = data.get(position);

holder.text1.setText(singleRow.getString());

holder.text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickList....
```

And in the click action:

```
int id = singleRow.getId();
```

In the activity file:

```
ArrayList<CustomObjectThatHasJustStringAndId> data = new ArrayList<>();
CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_layout, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ViewHolder` then for any views in your `ViewHolder` you can :

```
viewHolder.someTextView.setTag(id);
```

and to retrieve the same value:

```
(String) viewHolder.someTextView.getTag()
```

Comment: I am just using this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.custom_list, listItems); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter); `

Comment: You need to write your own custom adapter implementation for that, write a class extending `ArrayAdapter`